# Relocating .spyder-py3

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I just installed Anaconda Python 3.9 on a Windows 10 machine into a directory called C:\Dev because my company wants all development work done in  that directory.  They have a nanny called "Carbon Black" that screams when you try to execute any code not in that directory.

The installation creates a directory called
c:\users\username.spyder-py3\

Launching Spyder seems to call temp.py in this directory, which causes that "Carbon Black" to prevent Spyder from launching.

Can I relocate the .spyder-py3 directory and tell Python where it has been moved?

If not, is there a work-around to this?

Comment: Maybe the `--conf-dir` flag could be useful for you. To check all the flags available run from an Anaconda prompt with the env you have Spyder activated `spyder --help`

Comment: Thank you!  I copied the .spyder-py3 directory to the C:\Dev directory, then from an Anaconda Prompt launched spyder with spyder --conf-dir C:\Dev   Now everything seems to be working properly including the shortcut from the start menu.

Comment: Glad you managed to set things up :)